# Aggregating heterogeneous documents in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, mapreduce, aggregation-framework

I am writing a tool to inspect a MongoDB session store, in which the structure is namespaces containing variables containing information on the variables, roughly:

```
{
    "some namespace" : {
        "some variable" : {
            "t" : "serialization type",
            "b" : "data value",
            "c" : "java class type"
        },
        "some other variable in this namespace" : {
            "t" : "serialization type",
            "b" : "data value",
            "c" : "java class type"
        },
        ...
    },
    ... // more namespaces
}
```

The names of the namespaces and variables are all different. I wrote a map-reduce job to loop through the namespaces and loop through the variables in each namespace and emit for each variable in each namespace.

However, I want to try to switch to Mongo's aggregation framework to avoid potential write lock problems. Based on the docs, it seems I have to specify the names of the variables to $group on, which doesn't seem compatible with heterogeneous data like mine. Is there any way to involve iteration in an aggregation invocation?

Comment: Would be possible to change your schema a bit?

Comment: Also, what do you want your results to look like? What exactly are you aggregating?

Comment: I can't change the schema, unfortunately. My job is less about designing the database and more about looking into it to see how the employees at my company are using it. The freedom to basically put whatever in there is one of the reasons they chose Mongo, though it led to abuse, which is why I'm analyzing it. 

My results with the map-reduce version are of the form:
{namespace, variable, java class, serialization, frequency, total aggr size in bytes} for every unique combo of the first 4 values. Does that make sense?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently, to use the aggregation framework, you have to know the field names to write the query. There are [some](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-18794) [proposals](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-11392) to remove that limitation.

---

Right now, given your design, to use the aggregation framework, you probably have to consolidate at regular intervals your data using map-reduce to something more or less like that:

```
{
    namespaces: [
      { name: "some namespace",
        variables: [
          { name: "some variable",
            t : "serialization type",
            b : "data value",
            c : "java class type"
          },
          { name: "some other variable in this namespace",
            t : "serialization type",
            b : "data value",
            c : "java class type"
          },
          ... // more variables
        ]
      },
      ... // more namespaces
    ]
}
```

Now it would be relatively easy to query using the aggregation framework. Admitting you may work on stale data...

Comment: Yeah I think you're right. The problem is that map-reduce transformation would still take a write lock on the db, which is what I'm trying to avoid in the first place. I think I'll just need to try to make mapReduce as efficient as possible and just suck it up. Any idea why mapReduce takes a write lock on the db and not just on any collections involved?

Comment: @JohnK [Things are more complex than that](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/map-reduce-concurrency/#map-reduce-concurrency). As of 3.0.4, the read phase only takes a _read_ lock -- and will yield every 100 documents. Definitively *not* blocking. But you're right: when merging/replacing/reducing *the result in an *existing* output collection, the map-reduce job acquires a global lock blocking all other operations on the instance. That being said, you may want to use the `nonAtomic` flag for `merge` or `reduce` to somehow mitigate that drawback.

Comment: I considered nonAtomic, but the Mongo java driver doesn't seem to expose that capability. I dug in and saw that their implementation of DBObject extended HashMap, so I tried using a .put() call to set nonAtomic to true, but for reasons I don't understand it broke the query even though the json it produces seems well-formed. So you're saying if I write to a different DB, it wouldn't avoid the write lock on the DB I'm reading from because global means the entire mongo instance? What is the reason for this?

Comment: @JohnK As about the reason, I cannot tell. You should try to look into the source code or maybe directly contact the dev about that. Concerning the Java driver, and how to use the `nonAtomic` flag when running map-reduce job, you should definitively ask that as an other question. That way you could get all the required attention to this issue, and that would be a great reference for future visitors.

Comment: Did some digging, turns out Java driver 3.0 changed map-reduce to use java iterables and supports nonAtomic. My problem was using 2.x. I still don't understand why it didn't work, but I no longer care very much :)